# return a list of values that meet criteria in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to generate a list sorted by categories in my budget. For example, I want the column J to have a list of amount I have spent on Groceries generated from the table on the left. Is there a formula to do this?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/simk4.png)

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by using `SUMIF` function as follows:

[image: HERE]

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the IF statement. You could probably try something like:

IF(B2=Groceries,D2,0)

Read more about the IF function in Excel here: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-if-function